# wx.StaticBox size parameter not respected

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm trying to create a `wx.StaticBox` having a constant size, regardless to the size of the widget within. So I have a panel containing the following code:

```
box = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, 'BoxTitle', size=(200, 200))
bsizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(box, wx.VERTICAL)

text = wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Text')
bsizer.Add(text)

border = wx.BoxSizer()
border.Add(bsizer)
self.SetSizer(border)
```

However, the box simply wraps the `StaticText` widget within, instead of sticking to the specified 200x200 size. How do I make the box conform to a hard-coded size?

Comment: Running your code it work fine for me on MacOS. Is self in your example the top frame or some panel from a hierarchy? Note that you can always use like Mark said SetMaxSize or SetMinSize but this is not recommended in general as a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the following after creating your `StaticBox` it will force the size for you:

```
box.SetMaxSize((200,200))
```

Note that a `StaticText` box does not wrap its text, so if your text is wider than the `StaticBox` it will extend beyond the edge of the box (as least on OS X it does this, may behave differently on Windows).

**Update:**

On Windows the sizing behaves much differently - the `StaticBox` just shrinks around the text.

Although I agree with bogdan that explicitly setting a window size with `SetMinSize` or `SetMaxSize` is probably not a good idea (e.g. if system font size changes and the contents no longer fits nicely into the size constraints you've set), the StaticText control shrinks to the size of its contents and appears to pull everything with it unless you explicitly force size limits on its container.

I suspect your only option here is either to use `SetMaxSize` or `SetMinSize` on your box control, or try other control options other than a `StaticText`.  You could try the `HtmlWindow` as an alternative.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me in Win7. I had to go with a GridSizer instead. Thanks for the response and follow up.